# I see two jscv processes when invoked inside a service

Tags: tomcat, java, process

I'm using tomcat's jscv to start the server ** as a service ** as the user tomcat (using jscv -user tomcat "lots of other parameters"). My server runs fine, however my question is:

- Is it bad that when I do ps -ef | grep tomcat I see two 'identically invoked' processes (same parameters/call). One runs as root and one runs as tomcat - they both look like they are running a tomcat server. Is this the norm jscv behavior? Or by calling tomcat as an /etc/init.d/tomcat service, did I mess something up?

On centos 5.5 using sun java 1.6

Answer (score 2):

Check the PID (process id) and PPID (parent process id) values for the two processes. If you find that the PPID of one matches the PID of the other. This means that one process spawned (forked) the other one.

For the ownership change, it is usually done to drop the process privileges from root to unprivileged user for better system security.

In short, it can be considered normal.

Comment: yeah the two PIDs are different (but in the form of something like the root runs as 2272 and tomcat runs as 2273). Anyways thanks for your advice